# Soft input panel for 480x320 LCD screen

Tags: gui-design, touch-screen, keyboard, software, older-users

I'm working on a [Qt-based C++ project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(software)). The project includes a [480x320 TFT LCD screen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07N38B86S) for display. The screen is also capacitive and used for touch-based input. The screen is about the size of a credit card.

Qt does not supply a [soft input panel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_Input_Panel) (SIP, the virtual keyboard). Qt offers a [full QWERTY keyboard](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-basic-example.html) example. Obviously a full QWERTY won't do due to screen size constraints. I need to implement the SIP for the project.

I've been through Google Scholar and papers relating to [user interface design, small touch screens, and virtual keyboards](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=soft+input+panel+small+touchscreen+"user+interface"). I have not found guidance on the layout of the input panels. Poupyrev and Maruyama's [Tactile Interfaces for Small Touch Screens](http://www.ivanpoupyrev.com/e-library/2003/uist2003_tactilesmalldisplay.pdf) looks very promising, but it is missing the useful details.

My question is, what do the user interface folks recommend for the SIP? Specifically:

- How many screens
- Layout of keys on the screen
- How to transition between screens

---

Here is my first attempt at constructing the input panel:

[image]

The <kbd>UP</kbd> and <kbd>DOWN</kbd> arrow move three lines at a time.

The <kbd>BS</kbd> is backspace; the <kbd>RET</kbd> is enter/return.

All other screens have the <kbd>BACK</kbd> arrow (upper right). It is included for consistency. I don't want to change things for a novice user.

The <kbd>BACK</kbd> arrow and <kbd>RET</kbd> key are the same function. They exit the input panel and return the result to the caller function.

I created the graphics using [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/). I'm not a graphics guy and I realize they lack professional polish.

---

The touch-based input is used for initial configuration. Users will not need to regularly input data using it. *I.e.*, it is not a "texting" app.

The input character set is that of a customary "strong" password.

- Characters A - Z
- Characters a - z
- Characters 0 - 9
- Characters with diacritics
- Punctuation
- Backspace and Enter

Based on initial design and testing, I think the screen limits keys to a 9x6 arrangement, using 51 pixel square per key. Anything smaller than 51 pixels causes missed touch events using a finger.

[image]